# Difficult using angularJs routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created my different route with angularjs following tutorial instructions, but the result is different because I have a different url. My code :

```
<script>
   var app = angular.module('firstApp', ['ngRoute']);
   app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'})
        .when('/comments', {templateUrl: 'partials/comments.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
         enable:true,
         requireBase:false
      });
   }
}]);
</script>
```

In my **home.html** file I put that :

```
<h1>Titre de l'article</h1>

<p>Contenu de l'article</p>

<h2>3 commentaires</h2> <a href="#/comments">Voir les commentaires</a>
```

I have a result for my first route but when I click the link to see comments, I have this in my url : **http://localhost:9000/#!/#%2Fcomments**

and when I add '**!**' after '**#**' in the a href element, is work.
Ok, now I don't want to show # or ! in my links, I need a normal link for my different pages, like that : **http://localhost:9000/** or **http://localhost:9000/comments**

Comment: you have to configure server for the virtual paths when you use html5Mode

Comment: for all links I have !!??

Comment: yes of course... but can be done with mod-rewrite wildcards and regex or server  side routing config. Depends on server type